# How to force WebStorm to set public before implemented method?

Tags: webstorm

When I implement some public method(TypeScript) WebStorm doesn't set public before this method.
And I get `foo()` instead of `public foo()`
Can't find an answer how to force it to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try enabling **Use 'public' modifier** in **Settings** (**Preferences** for MacOS) **| Editor | Code Style | TypeScript > Code Generation**